# Syntax template for SAS partitioning of variance

Tags: syntax, sas, partitioning

For class I’m asked to see analyze the variance individually- with the presence of other variables AND WITHOUT the presence of variables.

What is the code to partition variance (I know I will input my own variable codes)

Not too sure what the syntax would be but I am very familiar with how to interpret output

Comment: Are you trying to do an ANOVA?

Comment: PROC ANOVA or GLM for MANOVA (see the examples under each of the procedures documentation)